# Job.properties file for Oozie using Hue dashboard

Tags: oozie, hue, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a setup with Hue 3.8 and HDP 2.3 installed through Ambari.
When I am trying to run a dummy script using Oozie dashboard, it creates a job.properties file for the same. This file contains wrong mapping for hdfs URL because of which the script fails.

Need help to understand from where this properties file is getting populated.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the HDFS section of the [hue.ini config file](http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/).

You should check this value:

```
[hadoop] 

 [[hdfs_clusters]]

   [[[default]]]

    # Enter the filesystem uri
    fs_defaultfs=hdfs://localhost:8020
```